# Customer and driver API capabilities

Tags: uber-api

Wanted to know if there is an option to send the driver and the customer a location provided from my system.
If so what API do I need ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Uber doesn't have API you are asking for. You can get more info on available API's on Uber documentation: https://developer.uber.com/docs.